# GTK window with Quartz [starting from an issue with GStreamer]

Tags: c, gcc, open-source, gtk, glib

I'm trying to get basic-tutorial-5 of the GStreamer SDK to work on OSX.

SDK downloaded from http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/pkg/osx/1.2.4.1/

tutorials (for 1.0) from http://cgit.freedesktop.org/~slomo/gst-sdk-tutorials/

I get the following error

```
basic-tutorial-5.c:5:10: fatal error: 'gst/video/videooverlay.h' file not found
```

when I run

```
gcc `pkg-config gstreamer-1.0 gtk+-3.0 --cflags --libs` basic-tutorial-5.c -o basic5
```

Any pointers would be helpful!

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

There is a `gst/video/videooverlay.h` in `/local/frameworks/Gstreamer.framework/Headers`.

The output of `pkg-config gstreamer-1.0 gtk+-3.0 --cflags --libs` doesn't include `/Library/Frameworks/Gstreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/Headers`

Thanks to @Biffen when using

```
    gcc `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-3.0` -o basic5 basic-tutorial-5.c -I/Library/Frameworks/Gstreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/Headers -framework GStreamer
```

There is a little more action:

```
        basic-tutorial-5.c:114:17: warning: 'gtk_button_new_from_stock' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  play_button = gtk_button_new_from_stock (GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_PLAY);
                ^
/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3/3.12.2/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkbutton.h:103:16: note: 
      'gtk_button_new_from_stock' declared here
GtkWidget*     gtk_button_new_from_stock    (const gchar    *stock_id);
               ^
basic-tutorial-5.c:114:44: warning: 'GtkStock' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  play_button = gtk_button_new_from_stock (GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_PLAY);
                                           ^
/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3/3.12.2/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/deprecated/gtkstock.h:747:38: note: 
      expanded from macro 'GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_PLAY'
#define GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_PLAY       ((GtkStock)"gtk-media-play")
                                     ^
/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3/3.12.2/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/deprecated/gtkstock.h:107:16: note: 
      'GtkStock' declared here
typedef char * GtkStock;
               ^
basic-tutorial-5.c:117:18: warning: 'gtk_button_new_from_stock' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  pause_button = gtk_button_new_from_stock (GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_PAUSE);
                 ^
/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3/3.12.2/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkbutton.h:103:16: note: 
      'gtk_button_new_from_stock' declared here
GtkWidget*     gtk_button_new_from_stock    (const gchar    *stock_id);
               ^
basic-tutorial-5.c:117:45: warning: 'GtkStock' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  pause_button = gtk_button_new_from_stock (GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_PAUSE);
                                            ^
/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3/3.12.2/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/deprecated/gtkstock.h:733:38: note: 
      expanded from macro 'GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_PAUSE'
#define GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_PAUSE      ((GtkStock)"gtk-media-pause")
                                     ^
/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3/3.12.2/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/deprecated/gtkstock.h:107:16: note: 
      'GtkStock' declared here
typedef char * GtkStock;
               ^
basic-tutorial-5.c:120:17: warning: 'gtk_button_new_from_stock' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  stop_button = gtk_button_new_from_stock (GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_STOP);
                ^
/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3/3.12.2/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkbutton.h:103:16: note: 
      'gtk_button_new_from_stock' declared here
GtkWidget*     gtk_button_new_from_stock    (const gchar    *stock_id);
               ^
basic-tutorial-5.c:120:44: warning: 'GtkStock' is deprecated
      [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
  stop_button = gtk_button_new_from_stock (GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_STOP);
                                           ^
/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3/3.12.2/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/deprecated/gtkstock.h:799:38: note: 
      expanded from macro 'GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_STOP'
#define GTK_STOCK_MEDIA_STOP       ((GtkStock)"gtk-media-stop")
                                     ^
/usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3/3.12.2/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/deprecated/gtkstock.h:107:16: note: 
      'GtkStock' declared here
typedef char * GtkStock;
               ^
6 warnings generated.
```

So it complies... This seems a huge step forward but still no cigar...

When I try to run basic5 I get:

```
(process:73178): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type 'gchar'
**
GLib-GObject:ERROR:gvaluetypes.c:455:_g_value_types_init: assertion failed: (type == G_TYPE_CHAR)
Abort trap: 6
```

## EDIT v2:

Thanks to nemequ I can now compile with `gcc -o basic5 basic-tutorial-5.c`pkg-config --libs --cflags gstreamer-1.0 gstreamer-video-1.0 gtk+-3.0`` and run `./basic5` to get the following error:

```
Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!

(basic5:77683): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display:
```

It seems that the gtk folder (and others, no doubt) are missing from the  `/Library/Frameworks/Gstreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/Headers` folder and so using the `pkg-config..` is a work-around, maybe.

If I run `./basic5` in an XQuartz terminal I get the following error:

```
Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path, verify that org.freedesktop.dbus-session.plist is loaded!

(basic5:78227): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: No GSettings schemas are installed on the system
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Anyone else have any ideas?

Comment: Is there a `gst/video/videooverlay.h` file? What is the output of `pkg-config gstreamer-1.0 gtk+-3.0 --cflags --libs`?

Comment: (I take it the file's full path is then `/local/frameworks/Gstreamer.framework/Headers/gst/video/videooverlay.h`?) I can't see `/local/frameworks/Gstreamer.framework/Headers` among the include directories. Does adding it manually solve *this* problem?

Comment: @Biffen. Yes, I see that too, now. How can I manually add it?

Comment: `-I /local/frameworks/Gstreamer.framework/Headers`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54332/discussion-between-eddie-sanders-and-biffen).

Comment: Try googling "Dynamic session lookup supported but failed: launchd did not provide a socket path".  There are about 3 thousand results here, so hopefully you can find the right answer somewhere in there.

Comment: @nemequ I'm now weary of installing too many other things for fear of tangling the web even further. My plan is to appeal to the local university comsci dept. Perhaps I've bitten off more than I can chew on this one! Thanks so much for all your time and help. You deserve the bounty.

Answer (score 2):

For the initial problem, the solution depends on your system so it's a bit difficult to give you a good answer, but gst/video/videooverlay.h is part of the `gstreamer-video-1.0` package, *not* `gstreamer-1.0`.

That said, if you're using the GStreamer SDK then according to the GStreamer SDK documentation, [you should be using -framework GStreamer](http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Mac+OS+X#InstallingonMacOSX-BuildCreatingnewprojects), not pkg-config.

As for the error you're seeing about "cannot register existing type", that tends to happen when you try to link against two different versions of the same library.  TBH I've never seen it happen with gchar, but it probably means you're trying to link to two different version of glib or gobject, which makes sense—the `gtk+-3.0` pkg-config file will pull in `glib-2.0` and `gobject-2.0` as dependencies, and they're both already included in the GStreamer SDK.  AFAICT GTK+ is also included in the GStreamer SDK, so try just getting rid of the pkg-config stuff:

```
gcc -o basic5 basic-tutorial-5.c -I/Library/Frameworks/Gstreamer.framework/Versions/1.0/Headers -framework GStreamer
```

Comment: If I just run it with the -I and -framwork I get a ''gtk/gtk.h' file not found' fatal error. There is no 'gtk' folder in the /Frameworks/Gstreamer.framework/Version/1.0/Header directory and I'm not sure where to get it from or how to install it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try following the directions at http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+on+Mac+OS+X#InstallingonMacOSX-Build#InstallingonMacOSX-BuildBuildingthetutorials ?  You should be able to just open up one of the XCode project files distributed with the GStreamer SDK and look at what they do.

Comment: Yip. I downloaded installed all the packages and tried the X-code route also. I then copied the tutorials and have been trying to compile them as above.

Comment: Look in the entire subdirectory for the gtk.h file.  On Linux you would do something like `find /Library/Frameworks/Gstreamer.framework/Versions/1.0 -name gtk.h`, not sure if that command will work on OS X.  Also, have you installed GTK+ separately?  That could easily cause a conflict...

Comment: No search results. How do I install it properly?

Comment: Try `find /Library/Frameworks/Gstreamer.framework -name gtk.h`.  It seems like you have it installed somehow since pkg-config isn't generating an error.  Did you install it separately?  Worst case scenario is you grab the flags you need from the gtk+-3.0 and pass them manually so you don't pull in extra copies of glib and gobject...

Comment: I don't know what's happened - I've tried so many things... I have gtk.h installed at /usr/local/Cellar/gtk+3/3.12.2/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtk.h. I think that's where pkg-config gets it from. So do I put another -I to that directory?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54371/discussion-between-eddie-sanders-and-nemequ).