# How to fix GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `gchar'

Tags: c++, gstreamer, node-gyp

I am in the process of building a node.js wrapper for gstreamer. I am able to build, and extract a lot of information and objects (eg. version, plugins, features, caps, and element factories.)

However, when I call gst_element_factory_make, or gst_element_factory_create I get the following output:

```
(<unknown>:27080): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: cannot register existing type `gchar'
**
 GLib-GObject:ERROR:gvaluetypes.c:457:_g_value_types_init: assertion failed: (type == G_TYPE_CHAR)
Abort trap: 6
```

The answer at [GTK window with Quartz [starting from an issue with GStreamer]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23777031/gtk-window-with-quartz-starting-from-an-issue-with-gstreamer) seems to indicate that there may be some sort of version conflict, however I am not experienced enough with C++ and make files to know if this is my problem. Below is the libraries section of my binding.gyp, which (by experimentation) is the least modules required to build, run and get a version.

```
"/Library/Frameworks/Gstreamer.framework/Libraries/libgobject-2.0.a",
"/Library/Frameworks/Gstreamer.framework/Libraries/libgstreamer-0.10.a",
"/Library/Frameworks/Gstreamer.framework/Libraries/libffi.a",
"/Library/Frameworks/Gstreamer.framework/Libraries/libglib-2.0.a",
"/Library/Frameworks/Gstreamer.framework/Libraries/libgmodule-2.0.a",
"/Library/Frameworks/Gstreamer.framework/Libraries/libiconv.a",
"/Library/Frameworks/Gstreamer.framework/Libraries/libintl.a",
"/Library/Frameworks/Gstreamer.framework/Libraries/libxml2.a"
```

I have created a small test project to illustrate my problem. It is in a zip file at http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00675589235220460725

Answer (score 1):

Getting this for 'gchar' is weird. One case where you get this error is if you have a stale copy of a plugin and hence you try to register the plugin GType twice.

What I'd do to figure is to run it as:

```
G_DEBUG="fatal_warnings" gdb --args ./your-app
```

and from gdb type 'run' and once it terminates 'bt' to get the backtrace. If this comes from plugin registration, you might want to look at the gst debug log (GST_DEBUG="*:6" to see if any plugin is found twice.

Comment: I had the same problem after I forgot the fact that I renamed my plugin.  grepping for 'adding plugin' in the log (w/ GST_DEBUG=6) showed that old plugin was loaded.  Removed it and the error is gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So, I found that I had gstreamer 0.10 installed, after updating to 1.0, fixing the minor code differences, and including the AppKit framework (I'm on OSX) I finally have been able to move past this issue.